# How to configure DNS for Mailgun with same TXT and CNAME?

Tags: dns, mailgun

Mailgun is telling me to set up a `TXT` record for `mg.mydomain.com` with a value of `v=spf1 ...` plus a `CNAME` record for `email.mg.mydomain.com` with value `mailgun.org`.

I did that, and mailgun verified my domain no problem. The issue is when I send emails, certain receiving mail servers are rejecting my emails with message "Sender address rejected: Domain not found". I'm pretty sure this is because "mg.mydomain.com" doesn't exist -- I don't have a `CNAME` for it. However, I can't create a `CNAME` for it because it's already used for the `TXT` record.

So now I don't know what to do. Can I put this `v=spf1` thing in a *different* `TXT` record so that I can free up the `mg.` `CNAME`, so that sender-verification will work on these picky servers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears the missing ingredient is an A record for `mg.mydomain.com`

**A**

```
mg.mydomain.com.  A  nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:
```

If **email.mg.mydomain.com** `CNAME` is in the same DNS zone as **mydomain.com**, **mg.mydomain.com**, etc. and there's an `A record` with the ip pointing back to the hostname then setting up the `CNAME`, `TXT`, and `MX` records should be straightforward:

**CNAME**

```
email.mg.mydomain.com.  CNAME   mailgun.org.
```

**TXT**

```
mydomain.com.   TXT  v=spf1 a include:mailgun.org ~all
```

(optional for receiving)

**MX**

```
mydomain.com.   MX  mxa.mailgun.org.
mydomain.com.   MX  mxb.mailgun.org.
```

Comment: Aha! I didn't think about using an `A` record. This DNS stuff is still kind of new to me, but I looked it up. That makes sense. They really should add that to their list of things to configure. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I agree that if they don't mention that in the documentation they definitely should :)

Comment: Which IP Address should be used in A record?

Comment: @SagarMahajan: It should be the IP that points to your mailserver/hostname.

Comment: To be explicit: Go to [your domains](https://mailgun.com/app/domains) on Mailgun, click on mydomain.com, and you should see an IP address listed under "Domain Information".  This is what the A record for mg.mydomain.com should be set to.  (Mailgun should include this in their documentation...)

Comment: Thanks for the tips @user20061. Mailgun still doesn't recognize that I set my CNAME correctly in CloudFlare. In CF, I have `CNAME email.mg is an alias of mailgun.org`. But https://app.mailgun.com/app/domains/mg.mydomain.com always says "None found" for `CNAME email.mg.mydomain.com`. Any ideas? Thanks.